# jasper server conditional mandatory on input controls

Tags: jasperserver

My question relates to jasper server 3.71

How can I conditionally make an input control mandatory. I wish to force the user to select from one query or another. In my case they must select from a list of Divisions OR from a list of Clients.

With thanks

Mark

Answer (score 1):

This is not directly supported, however you could use a scenario where you define a third parameter which checks if either one or the other parameter is set. If the configuration is invalid you show an error message within the report instead of data.

Parameters:

- **parameter1**, type: string, default value: none - deployed as input control
- **parameter2**, type: string, default value: none - deployed as input control
- **verification**, type: Boolean, default value: `$P{parameter1} != null || $P{parameter2} != null` - not deployed as input control

Band/Field Configurations:

- As printWhen Expression of the detail band you add `$P{verification}` that means it will only be shown if the default expression for the *verification* parameter is `true`.
- Define a text field in e.g. the title band giving an error message that either one of *parameter1* and *parameter2* need to be filled.